# Is the following ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ principal?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to learn algebraic number theory on my own. I have decided to play with many examples first, rather than try to learn the general theory first.

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ and consider the ideal $I = (2, 1+\sqrt{5})$ in $R$. I suspect that $I$ is not a principal ideal. I tried to prove it by contradiction, but I got a little bogged down in the details.

I noticed that in $R$, one has $4 = 2^2 = (1+\sqrt{5})(-1+\sqrt{5}) = (3+\sqrt{5})(3-\sqrt{5})$. These do seem like different factorizations of $4$ in $R$, but I did not think about what the units in $R$ are. It is this remark which actually inspired the question.

Comment: That ring is not integrally closed which may cause you some trouble (you picked an ideal lying over 2 which divides the index of $R$ in the maximal order). By Dirichlet you only have to worry about units from roots of unity (in particular from $\zeta_5$) but I think that they’re missing from your $R$ (but would be in its integral closure).

Comment: As @TokenToucan comments, your ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{5}]$ is not integrally closed, that is, is not the ring of algebraic integers in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{5})$, so will have some bad features. Should be $\mathbb Z[{1+\sqrt{5}\over 2}]$. So, are you sure that this is the question you want to ask?

Comment: @paulgarrett, I realize this. I am learning about some "pathological" example on purpose. This will help me come up with counterexamples later on for instance.

Comment: @Malkoun, ok, then, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If $(2, 1+\sqrt{5})=(\alpha)$ where $\alpha=m+n\sqrt{5}$ then
$$2= \alpha \beta \\
1+\sqrt{5}=\alpha \gamma$$
for some $\beta, \gamma \in \sqrt{5}$.

Now use the norm $N(a+b\sqrt{5})=a^2-5b^2$. This implies that $N(\alpha), N(\beta), N(\gamma) \in \{  \pm 1, \pm 2 , \pm 4 \}$.

BUT, $N(a+b\sqrt{5}) \equiv a^2 \neq \pm 2 \pmod{5}$.

Deduce from here that either $\alpha$ is an unit or $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are units.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thank you. So an element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is a unit iff its norm is $\pm 1$? I think I can finish the argument now, since if $\alpha$ is a unit, then $I = R$, which is a contradiction, and if $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are units, then $2$ and $1+\sqrt{5}$ are associates, which is not the case and thus also leads to a contradiction. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. For one direction use $N(a+b\sqrt{5})=(a+b\sqrt{5})(a-b\sqrt{5})$. If this is $\pm 1$ then it is easy to see that $a+\b\sqrt{5}$ is an unit. The other implication follows immediately from the fact that $N$ is multiplicative. @Malkoun

Comment: ah yes, true! Thank you once more.

Comment: By the way, I did prove in a similar way that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{29}]$ is not a PID. This was one of the questions at the end of J.S. Milne's ANT lecture notes (the "two-hour examination"). My plan is to learn the subject by solving problems.

Comment: @Malkoun Marcus’s Number Fields is a great book with lots of problems. Its only downside is that he avoids local methods, but you can find that in most other books like Milne (you might think of it as a perk too, as simplifying theorems with localization could be a good exercise :)).

Comment: @Malkoun a recent (and inexpensive) book, good for self-study, that starts with quadratic fields. By Lehman   https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-52/

Comment: @TokenToucan, I own a copy of Markus's book. I will try to solve some problems from it. Thank you!